# Prevent Saving in excel couldn't be saved?

Tags: excel, save

This may sound silly but I'm trying to prevent saving in Excel Workbook by using the code below in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

However, after pressing `Ctrl + s`, and close the workbook, when reopening it, the code wasn't saved.

Any idea why this happen ?

Comment: It does sound silly :-) . I can't tell if you want to save or not. Your title seems to be saying both, as does your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good thing - it means your code is working right.  Your code prevented you from saving the workbook yourself.  I have this in a couple applications I have made, the way around it is to make a sub as follows:

```
sub saveTheWB()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
end sub
```

You have to run this sub every time you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

That's right because the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event handler is firing and cancelling the save operation.

In the Immediate window of The IDE, run `Application.EnableEvents = False` before saving your workbook and it will save with the code.

Don't forget to run `Application.EnableEvents = True` after!